# Generate and save .json file from blob

Tags: javascript, html, json, blob

I am using a code to generate a file blob (`function createJsonBlob()` ) followed by a function that creates a temporary anchor to download the blob (`saveAsJsonFile()` ). Once the download button is clicked, the resulting file (`image.json`) is downloaded and saved in the user PC download folder.

I want instead that after pressing the download button, the `image.json` file is saved in a directory of my choice inside the server (e.g the root folder). How can I do this?

```
     /**
     * Creates a json object and from it a file blob. The json object
     * additionally adds types of the shapes it holds since json does
     * not store functions.
     *
     * @returns {Blob} A file blob with all the shapes in a json format.
     */      

function createJsonBlob() {
            let lst = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < drawer.shapes.length; i++) {
                let tmp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(drawer.shapes[i]));
                tmp['type'] = drawer.shapes[i].__proto__.constructor.name;
                lst.push(tmp);
            }
            return new Blob([JSON.stringify(lst)], {type: 'application/json'});
        } 
/**
 * Create a temporary anchor to download a blob, click it
 * and then remove it.
 */
    
    function saveAsJsonFile() {
            let tmp = window.document.createElement('a');
            tmp.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(createJsonBlob());
            tmp.download = 'image.json';
            document.body.appendChild(tmp);
            tmp.click();
            document.body.removeChild(tmp);
        }

    // Add download event for anchor in navigation bar.
    document.getElementById('img-save').addEventListener('click', saveAsJsonFile);
```

note: Code originally from ttps://github.com/JonSteinn/Web-Paint

Comment: This question was answered somewhere else on stackoverflow but I'll reiterate what was said: You cannot force a directory onto the user, however, a user can change his browser settings to change the download location.  Change download location:   [Chrome](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Download-Location-in-Chrome%3famp=1)  [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959747)

Comment: I edited the question. I meant saving the .json file in a folder in the server and not in the user PC once the user presses the button.

Comment: Write a server that accepts JSON files (using a secured API), do a HTTP POST request to it (e.g. using `fetch`) instead of a download.